# React Router - Framer motion how to conditionally update animation initial / exit values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, framer-motion

I am trying to make a smooth full page scroll effect when transitioning between routes using the mouse wheel.

I have successfully implemented the logic for scrolling between between routes and the route hierarchy, mousewheel-up scrolls up and vice versa as shown below (note the below code is using React Context but in the actual app it is just a normal component):

AnimatedRoutes.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Main from "./Main";
import Skills from "./Skills";
import AboutMe from "./AboutMe";
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  useLocation,
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

export default function AnimatedRoutes() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />} />
        <Route path="/aboutme" element={<AboutMe />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```

Context.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Context = React.createContext();

function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => handleNavigation(e));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", (e) => handleNavigation(e));
    };
  }, [location]);

  function handleNavigation(e) {
    if (location.pathname.includes("/work/")) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (e.deltaY > 1 && location.pathname === "/") {
        navigate("/skills");
      } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && location.pathname === "/skills") {
        navigate("");
      } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && location.pathname === "/skills") {
        navigate("/aboutme");
      } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && location.pathname === "/aboutme") {
        navigate("/skills");
      }
    }
  }

  return <Context.Provider value={{}}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
}

export { ContextProvider, Context };
```

The mouse wheel down transitions are "/" -> "/skills" -> "/aboutme"

when following this static path having the following initial and exit animations are appropriate:

Main.js

```react
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="main--container"
      initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -1000, transition: { duration: 0.8 } }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 0.8 } }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -1000, transition: { duration: 0.8 } }}
    >
      <p>use mousewheel to scroll down and up </p>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I require **dynamic** initial and exit values between transitions.

For Skills.js (the middle Route):
going from "/" to "/skills" to "/aboutme" is fine for me to have the initial value for y as 1000 and exit value as -1000, however when scrolling from "/skills" to "/" I need the exit value to now be 1000.

How can I have dynamically changing values? is there a better way to implement this?

I have uploaded a simple replicable example in codesandbox below:

[image: Edit fast-sky-kbm006]

I have been stuck on this issues for days and I cannot see a simple solution for it